# Is the tense and conjugation in my sentence understandable?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, conjugations, sentence

田中は私が花瓶を壊したと言う、が私ではなかった。

Tanaka says that I broke the vase, but it wasn't me.

I'm figuring out how to make complex sentences so I'll be prepared to write short stories!
I want to see if this means what I intended it to, if there's any grammatical changes to be made, or if there's better word choice.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is correct but you can only do 壊したというが、私ではない。 or (in an over the top dramatic way) 壊したと言う。が、私ではない. You can’t do 壊したと言う、が私ではない